# Unable to install Python GAE correctly in ubuntu

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu

Trying to learn how to use GAE Python SDK. I have unzipped the package to my home directory in Ubuntu, made a new directory with the name "GoogleApps" in the home directory too. I wrote the two files mentioned in the [Hello, World! Example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) at GAE help putting them in a directory I named "helloworld" placed inside "GoogleApps". But I wasn't able to test the application, I entered the following to the terminal:  google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/ it returned a lot of things ending with "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'helloworld'"
I tried opening the dev app server using the command mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver), it returned "dev_appserver.py: command not found". Through some googling I managed to insert the path to GAE commands in .profile, I put PATH="$PATH:/home/mohamed/google_appengine. Why isn't it working?

A marginal question:Is there is a GUI for GAE Python SDK on linux?

Comment: Did you add python?  There isn't a separate GUI, but there's a plugin that works with Eclipse: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/

I've personally stopped using Eclipse because I found it slow and laggy, but it might be useful to get started.

Comment: Hi, My Ubuntu Software Center says that Python is installed, version 2.7.4. I have figured out that the path for GAE commands should be put in the .bashrc file not the .profile, is that true? After doing this, GAE commands were readable to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I have found a detailed walk-through into installing GAE on Linux [here](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6002660/howto-start-a-new-project-in-app-engine-for-linux-every-step-of-the-hw1-help-video-explained#cs253) I have installed it successfully and managed to complete the assignment!